# The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding

Tags: reactjs, json, visual-studio-code, encoding

Is it related or not I don't know but when I install firebase and open VS Code again, this problem appeared in package.json and package-lock.json when click to 'Open anyway' button Text-Editor this nulnulnul issue come up

nul problem:
[image: nul problem]

When I open package.json file with Hex Editor shown like this

with hex editor:
[image: with hex editor]

Edit:

I deleted package.json files and install all packages again and it works

Comment: is it also empty if you use `vi`, if so something has filled the file with `00` and you are out of luck if you don't have version control/backup, what does `od` show about the file

Comment: Before I try on vi deleted package.json file and now trying to install packages again, it seems easer

Answer (score 0):

Had similar experience and these are the steps I took.

If you've push the project to github or any source control system, copy the package.json file in the repo, delete the corrupted package.json file in the project folder, then paste the copied package.json file on your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

I went through this problem
The cause of the problem was that I had the files in extension Example.rar
Then instead of extracting the files by decompressing them
I dragged it through a program window through
instead of extracting it naturally
I was using a system at the time ubuntu  And I want to access the files through a program "vs code"
The program I was using is called "Archive Manager"

The Archive Manager in Ubuntu is a utility program that allows users to manage compressed archives, such as ZIP, TAR, RAR, GZIP, and BZIP

Solve the problem if you go through the same experience as me
Unzip the files normally
Then try to make sure the files are working

Answer (score -1):

just extract the files before you even open the zipped files in the vs code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).